# clearing all setTimeout set by a for loop not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I want to clear all remaining timeouts set by a for loop like this:

```js
let voiceDictatePoints = [4.5, 7.5, 8.5];
let voiceDictateTimeouts;


for(let i = 0; i < voiceDictatePoints.length; i++){
    voiceDictateTimeouts = setTimeout(voiceDictatePlay, voiceDictatePoints[i] * 1000);
    
    function voiceDictatePlay(i) {
       console.log('voiceDictatePlay executes');
    }
    
}

// 500 miliseconds after execution of first timeout we try to clear all of them 
setTimeout(() => clearVoiceDictateTimeouts(), 5000);

// function to clear all set timeouts
function clearVoiceDictateTimeouts() {
console.log('all timeouts should be cleared but ...');
  for(let i = 0; i < voiceDictatePoints.length; i++){
      clearTimeout(voiceDictateTimeouts); 
  }
}
```

But as you see one of the timeouts cleared and another not! How can I fix this? what is happening there?

I don't want to make this complicated. a solution based on my code structure would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`voiceDictateTimeouts` should be an array, you can push each timeout into the array and then loop over the array clearing each timeout.

```js
let voiceDictatePoints = [4.5, 7.5, 8.5];
let voiceDictateTimeouts = [];


for(let i = 0; i < voiceDictatePoints.length; i++){
    voiceDictateTimeouts.push(setTimeout(voiceDictatePlay, voiceDictatePoints[i] * 1000));
}

// function to clear all set timeouts
function clearVoiceDictateTimeouts() {
    for(let i = 0; i < voiceDictatePoints.length; i++){
        clearTimeout(voiceDictateTimeouts[i]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well Done Iron Man!